# Declaración de variables en PHP

Tags: php, php7

¿Que diferencia hay en declarar variables así en PHP:

```
var $variable
```

o

```
$variable
```

He visto ejemplos de las dos formas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables en PHP bajo un contexto de programación procedimental se declaran solamente con la estructura de:

```
$nombreVariable = valorAsignado;
```

En la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.basics.php) puedes consultar a detalle las reglas para mas contexto.

Actualmente nos encontramos en la versión 7.4.5 y usar una sintaxis antigua con el identificador `var` derivará en un error tal como:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting end of file in

Por otro lado en un estilo orientado a objetos *funcionará* siempre y cuando no le declares un modificador de acceso a la propiedad.

Es decir lo siguiente funcionará:

```
class Name
{
    var $name = "algo";
}
```

Pero lo siguiente dará el mismo error ya antes mencionado:

```
class Name
{
    $name = "algo";
}
```

Lo cual es si supone un problema grave al no permitir declarar el alcance que cada propiedad según su naturaleza de existencia y uso requiera.

Lo anterior ocurre por que como menciona la propia [documentación de PHP:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

Que se puede traducir como:

> Las propiedades de una clase deben ser definidas como pública, privada o protegida. Si son declaradas usando `var` entonces las propiedades serán definidas como públicas.

En resumen....

No uses la palabra clave `var` no importa si usas un estilo procedimental u orientado a objetos, salvo aquellos casos donde sea estrictamente necesario por ejemplo algún proyecto *legacy* con un PHP muy muy viejo.

Si estás haciendo POO entonces es mejor que cada propiedad y método tenga su modificador de acceso claramente declarado.

**Referencias**

- [var keyword status](https://www.php.net/releases/5_1_3.php)
- [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)